# How does HMRC collect underpaid tax

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, tax-deduction

In 2022/23 tax year, I was working for a UK employer and had a base salary around 100k GBP. My tax code was 1071T, which apparently means that I had a tax free allowance of 10710 per year (according to [this answer here](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/148225/124761)). During that year, I also registered as a sole trader and received around 25k GBP from my self-employment.

In July 2023 I submitted a self assessment form to HMRC, where I entered my 25k GBP income. A few days after that my tax code changed to K361X, which means I now have a negative tax free allowance of -3160. Later, in my August 2023 payslip from my main employment, I noticed that my Income Tax increased by ~500 GBP.

This tax increase apparently means that HMRC decided that I had not paid enough tax in the 2022/23 tax year, and now collects it from my main employment's salary in the 2023/24 year. Can somebody clarify how this process of collecting underpaid tax works?

1. Am I correct in assuming that the reason for the income tax increase is caused by the fact that in 2022/23 I paid my main employment taxes based on the 10710 GBP tax free allowance, but the additional income from my self-employment reduced that amount, and now I need to pay additional tax?
2. If (1) is true, then why was the additional tax amount not included into my self-assessment payment? Why did HMRC decide to take it from my main employment's salary?
3. How can I find out the total amount of extra tax that HMRC intends to collect, and over what period?
4. In such cases, does HMRC try to spread the additional tax payments over 12 months? Or over the months remaining until the end of 2023/24 tax year? Or over some other period?

Comment: When you submitted your self assessment, what did you tick on the box for "Do you want us to collect underpaid tax through your tax code"?

Comment: @Vicky the self assessment form said `If you owe less than £3,000 for the 2022–23 tax year, we’ll try to collect the tax through your wages or pension by adjusting your 2024–25 tax code`. I have not opted out of that, but I was under the impression it should not apply to me now because (1) I think I owe more than 3k, and (2) it says it will adjust the 2024–25 tax code, but we are currently still in the 2023-24 year

Comment: You should have received a coding notice explaining how K361X was calculated. What does it say? If you didn't get it, look in your online tax account.